# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in reactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, split

I want to cut a string (it's in an object) in 3 words (after "-"), my application is developed with reactJS, how to fixed this problem ?.
I want to return the line after "-".
NOTE: data is defined and displayed, but i want cut the String (name) after "-"
I want to display the channel like this :
***tst ab

deb

azerty bla***

problem :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

object :

```
email: "tst@gmail.com"
idclient: 74
name: "tst ab - deb - azerty bla"
poste: "PDG"
soct: "entrp"
phone: "1111111"
```

mypage front :

```
....
     <tr>
         <td><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Name</td>
         <td> {this.state.clientById.name.split(' - ')} </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(this.state.clientById)`?

Comment: I get object, I have already created the object :)

Comment: Yes so does it have a `name` field?

Comment: Can you put your app.js code or bit more code of how and when you are creating the object.

Comment: yes, i want to return the line after '-'

Answer (score 1):

The error might be during the initial render where `this.state.clientById` might not have `name` property. If the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is allowed in your application, you can use the following snippet:

```
<td> {this.state?.clientById?.name?.split(' - ').join('\n')} </td>
```

Solution without optional chaining, just in case:

```
<td> { this.state.clientById
       && this.state.clientById.name
       && this.state.clientById.name.split(' - ').join('\n')
     }
</td>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, just keep in mind that optional chaining isn't available in all browsers.

Comment: Please can you create a sample application on codepen or codesandbox with one dummy object and share here. It will make it lot easier for us to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

name.split('-') will return an array so you need to store in variable and iteration it

Comment: But here the `.split()` doesn't execute

Comment: i want return the line after "-", the problem I don't know how

Comment: The above error says that `this.state.clientById` is undefined. Please can you provide more code like how your state is and how it is getting updated or what does logging your `this.state.clientById` return ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring due to empty or null property "name" in "clientById". If we try to call split on undefined it will give error.

Try this one to get desired output. It will work in all browser.

```
 <td> {this.state.clientById && this.state.clientById.name && this.state.clientById.name.split(' - ').map(item => {
                   return (<div> {item} </div>)
       } </td>
```

Comment: the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your component may be rendering before the state is initialized and at that time `this.state.clientById.name` may still be undefined, try adding a check bofore executing the `split` like this.

```
 <td> {
          this.state.clientById && 
          this.state.clientById.name && 
          this.state.clientById.name.split(' - ')
      } 
</td>
```

This will make sure that `this.state.clientById.name` is defined before trying to split it.